# Get the annotation id or reference in ios mapview

Tags: xcode, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview, callout

I draw some annotations in `viewdidload` function and I want to press a button and the annotation which I want callout will automatically show out.
The function is

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:self.annotation animated:YES];
```

but i got some problem that `self.annotation` can't pass the compiler check, I don't know how to solve this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: please show some code and also try to better describe the issue

Answer (score 0):

Is `self` your view controller? Does it have a property called annotation?